Typescript union error when trying to render JSX conditionally based on the props being passed to the component
I am new to software development and typescript so please forgive me for any atrocities in my code.
** I have three types, one of them being a union.**
types.ts
export type CoachType = {
  id: number,
  firstName: string,
  type: string,
  lastName: string,
  email: string,
  city: string,
  state: string,
  picture: string
  reviews: Array<{id: number; title: string; body: string; rating: number; likes: Array<{id: number; agree: boolean}>}>
}

export type ReviewType = {
  id: number,
  rating: number,
  type: string,
  title: string,
  body: string,
  likes: Array<{id: number; agree: boolean}>
}

export type CardType = CoachType | ReviewType;

export type ReviewsInterface = {
  reviews: ReviewType[]
}


**I then check the props being passed to a component looking at the type property to conditionally render some JSX. **
index.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardHeader from "@mui/material/CardHeader";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import IconButton, { IconButtonProps } from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { red } from "@mui/material/colors";
import FavoriteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import { CardType, ReviewType } from "../../common/types";

interface ExpandMoreProps extends IconButtonProps {
  expand: boolean;
}

const ExpandMore = styled((props: ExpandMoreProps) => {
  const { expand, ...other } = props;
  return <IconButton {...other} />;
})(({ theme, expand }) => ({
  transform: !expand ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(180deg)",
  marginLeft: "auto",
  transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
  }),
}));

export default function CoachCard(props: CardType) {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const averageRating = (reviews: Array<ReviewType>): string => {
    const numberOfRatings = reviews.length;
    let totalOfReviews = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRatings; i++) {
      totalOfReviews += reviews[i].rating;
    }
    const average = totalOfReviews / numberOfRatings;
    return `Average Rating: ${average}/10`;
  };

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };
  console.log(props, "checking props")
  return(
    <>
      { props.type === 'coach' ? (
          <Card sx={{ width: 345 }}>
          <CardHeader
            className="cardHeader"
            onClick={() => navigate(`/coach/${props.id}`)}
            avatar={
              <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: red[500] }} aria-label="recipe">
                R
              </Avatar>
            }
            title={`${props.firstName} ${props.lastName}`}
            subheader={averageRating(props.reviews)}
          />
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="194"
            image={props.picture}
            alt="Coach"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              <div>City: {props.city}</div>
              <div>State: {props.state}</div>
              <div>Email: {props.email}</div>
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <ExpandMore
              expand={expanded}
              onClick={handleExpandClick}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              {/* <ExpandMoreIcon /> */}
            </ExpandMore>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      ) : (
        <Card sx={{ width: 345 }}>
        <CardHeader
          className="cardHeader"
          onClick={() => navigate(`/coach/${props.id}`)}
          avatar={
            <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: red[500] }} aria-label="recipe">
              R
            </Avatar>
          }
          title={`${props.firstName} ${props.title}`}
          subheader={props.title}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            <div>City: {props.title}</div>
            <div>State: {props.body}</div>
            <div>Email: {props.body}</div>
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <FavoriteIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <ExpandMore
            expand={expanded}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            {/* <ExpandMoreIcon /> */}
          </ExpandMore>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
      )}
    </>
  )
}


It is erroring out saying
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'CardType'.
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'ReviewType'.
The errors continue on the else statement saying pretty much the same only certain props don't exist on CoachType and CardType
I've tried using switch cases and other ways of conditional rendering but nothing is working. I've checked various posts and docs and can't figure out what I'm messing up with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Set the property type to either 'coach' or 'review' instead of string, eg.. for the Coach Type,  instead of doing type: string put type: 'coach'  and then for review type: 'review',  this will allow Typescript to narrow the type.
eg.  Typescript Playground
